# Where does Console2 reads fonts from?

Tags: fonts, console2

I can only see couple of fonts listed on the settings of console2 even though I have installed lots of fonts in my system. Where does the console2 reads the fonts from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only [Monospaced Fonts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font) are allowed in console2.

Comment: I installed a font called monaco as suggested by this tutorial http://tech.xster.net/tips/quake-style-drop-down-terminal-for-windows/ isn't that a momospaced font?

Comment: I downloaded Monaco from here http://www.sitepoint.com/top-10-programming-fonts/ and it showed up as font in console2. But If it dosn't work you can try to add this key to your registry `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Console\TrueTypeFont]
"000"="Monaco"` (editing registry is at your own risk)